# what should I do to get the credentials of the user to the firebase realtime database as soon as the user logs in to the website

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, credentials

I am using google authorization through firebase and it works properly also but what should I do to get the credentials of the user to the firebase real-time database as soon as the user logs in to the website.

Comment: Have a look at the [corresponding doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start).

Comment: Answer below, but please read this page on [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for your web site to get the user's credentials from Google Authentication. That would be a **huge** security risk.

There is also typically no need to store the user's credentials in your own database. Firebase already stores the user's credentials (securely) on the client itself, and restores those when the page reloads.

Comment: alright sir,
so should I go for authentication through email and password instead of using google authentication to store the user data into the realtime database??

also is it the only case with web apps because a colleague of mine was able to authenticate through google and also save the data to the realtime database when he was working on an android app??

Comment: You will have to determine for yourself what authentication provider(s) you want to support. But if you use one of the default providers, you should **not** store the email/password for the users in your own database. Storing passwords in cleartext is a huge security concern.